# What If a variable is defined as "static " in .h file?

Tags: c++

windows 8, clang

hh.h file:

```
#ifndef _H_
#define _H_
#include<string>
using std::string;
static string m; // If m is defined as static, the promble of multiple definitions will be solved.
#endif
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "hh.h"
int foo()
{
    m = "456";
}
```

bar.cpp

```
#include "hh.h"
int main()
{
m = "123";
}
```

compiling with -c for foo.cpp and bar.cpp

Then,I use "nm" to check the export symbol table

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .ctors
00000000 d .data
00000000 d .eh_frame
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
00000000 b m  // a local var, as 'b'
// others
```

Otherwise, if I define the "string m " with no qualifier static, such as

hh.h file:

```
#ifndef _H_
#define _H_
#include<string>
using std::string;
string m;
#endif
```

And , I use "nm" to check the export symbol table,

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .ctors
00000000 d .data
00000000 d .eh_frame
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
00000000 B m  // a global var, as 'B'
// others
```

The linker tells that variable m is "multiple definitions".

My thought is that , in hh.h file, I write a  defensive statement for hh.h to  protect it from being included multiple times(I use -E option to check the precompiling file).Then, if hh.h will not be included over twice in final object file, why a global variable(like m) declard in header file can be reached by linker over times?This is my first question.

On the other hand, if I declare m as staic, which means that m will be used only by those who includes the header file where m be declared.But I hope the variable m can be shared as a global variable. This is my second question.

If there are any wrong understands in my thought, please point it out.Thanks!

Comment: You will get a separate instance of that variable in each cpp file

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declaring a variable as `static` in a header file has the exact same effect as declaring it as `static` in every file which includes that header. Each translation unit (i.e, `.cpp` file) will end up with their own instance of that variable, separate from the ones in other translation units. This is incredibly confusing, and is almost certainly not what you want. Don't do it.

Comment: As OP stated _But I hope the variable m can be shared as a global variable._ may be, it's worth to mention that `extern` is the better choice in this case.

Comment: @duskwuff you are right.In fact, I want to share m in multiple files, such as foo.cpp and bar.cpp. Because I do not want to write "extern string m" in the file who will share m. I , therefore, think whether I can write it into a header file ,which can avoid writing extern keyword over and over again

Comment: @W.Cameron it seems that `extern` is the right choice for your problem but I wouldn't recommend this without mentioning the [Static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) and how to fix it with a singleton e.g. [Meyers Singleton](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton). The former isn't necessarily an issue for any global variable (depends on how it is constructed and an what other things it depends on) but the latter is a solution in any case.